# DropdownList selected value not saved in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, c#-5.0

I need big help from here i am new to Asp.net MVC 4 Application development , actually i faced a problem when i save my dropdownlist selected value in a database ,after i click my submit button.

I use Debug pointer to check values in a HTTP post object but it doesn't contain dropdownlist select value it always display null value in a  division raw I need some expert advice to solve that problem i go through the several examples and try several times but still i haven't proper solution for that.

Model class:

```
public partial class tblEmployee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfJoin { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }

    public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
    public virtual tblDivision Divisions { get; set; }
}


public partial class tblDivision
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SelectId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller class:

```
namespace EmpiteHrSystem.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private EmpiteContext db = new EmpiteContext();

        public ActionResult Create()
        { 
            ViewBag.DivisionOptions = new SelectList(db.tblDivisions, "value","Division");

            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tblEmployee tblemployee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                { 
                    db.Entry(tblemployee).State = EntityState.Added;

                    db.tblEmployees.Add(tblemployee);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ae)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ae.Message);

                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model EmpiteHrSystem.Models.tblEmployee
@{  ViewBag.Title = "Create"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId) 

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Office)*@

@Html.DropDownList("DivisionOptions")

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Division)

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Comment: It's really not clear what the problem is.  Which value is empty?  Does the HTML form contain an element for that value?  Please be specific about the problem description.

Comment: @David actaully Dropdownlist fill with values from database its already done correctly the problem is when i select the item in dropdownlist and click submit button it not save dropdownlist select value in a database to check that problem i use debug point near to create action when i check  tblemployee object it had Division field with null value but when i use EditorFor its already have data :(

Comment: Actually i use dropdownlist in wrong way ? OR somebody know best way to do that task , use in another technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DivisionOptions` drop down list is not being bound back to the model properly because it is the wrong name.  Your model is looking for a property with the name **Division** while your drop down list is being bound to **DivisionOptions**.  You have a few options.

1. Use a strongly typed helper

   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Division, (SelectList)ViewBag.DivisionOptions)
2. Rename your currrent code and pass in the SelectList

   @Html.DropDownList("Division", (SelectList)ViewBag.DivisionOptions)